# Set theory equivalency: Why is $(A-B) \cup (B-A)$ equal to $(B^c- A^c) \cup (A^c - B^c)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In a textbook exercise about "exclusive OR", the author asks us to find an equivalent of
(A<sup>∁</sup> − B<sup>∁</sup>) ∪ (B<sup>∁</sup> − A<sup>∁</sup>).

The correction option is derived as follows:

=(A<sup>∁</sup> − B<sup>∁</sup>) ∪ (B<sup>∁</sup> − A<sup>∁</sup>) [1]
= (B − A) ∪ (A − B) [2] 
= (A − B) ∪ (B − A)[3]

He didn't even cite a rule, so I'm supposing it's obvious. But I can't figure out the derivation from [1] to [2]?

**BTW**: in case anyone is interested, this is from an introductory textbook, Winters (2016) *Elements of Formal Semantics: An Introduction to the Mathematical Theory of Meaning in Natural Language*.

Comment: $U\setminus V=U\cap V^c.$ So $$V^c\setminus U^c=V^c\cap (U^c)^c=V^c\cap U=U\setminus V.$$

Comment: It seems he is assuming it is clear that $M^c -N^c = N-M$.  This can be verified by definitions.  $M^c - N^c$ is "all the elements in $M^c$ that are not in $N^c$" = "all the elements that are not in $M$ that are not not in $N$" ="all the elements that are not in $M$ there *are* in $N$" = "all the elements that are in $N$ that are not in $M$ $=N-M$.   This was probably proven earlier in the text.

Comment: Maybe it was my upbringing but I like to *feel* what sets mean so I like the talk out an identity like that.  However using notation and definitions makes it very mechanically easy to prove as Thomas Andrews comment shows might actually be easier than my "So you see..." argument.  $M\setminus N=M\cap N^c$ so $A^c\setminus B^c = A^c\cap (B^c)^c=A^c \cap B=B\cap A^c = B\setminus A$.  Easy. but to me not so easy to *feel*.

Comment: @fleablood I perfectly understand what you mean... and I also *feel* it. However, I think that it is interesting to try to define what *feel* means here. Not easy on my side!

Comment: Thanks @ThomasAndrews It seems very easy now, that you've explained it.

Comment: @fleablood thanks for helping me _feel_ it too! Though, there's a small typo in the third step, "all the elements that are not in  ~there~ [that] are in " and the author never actually proved it before.

Comment: One tricky problem with this "definition" of $\setminus$ is that only works inside a fixed universe set, $U$ containing both $X$ and $Y.$ But in reality, $X\setminus Y$ is the same for any $U\supset X\cup Y.$ But $X^c$ and $Y^c$ are really only defined in terms of a specific $U.$ So my first comment, while the capturing the heart of it, is not a good proof. You really need to show $a\in U\setminus V$ if and only if $a\in V^c\setminus U^c.$ But for intuition, my comment is the right start.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews thanks for the disclaimer. In this case, we're assuming a fixed set of entities _E_ over which A and B are defined. So, this problem shouldn't arise.

Comment: Yeah, my disclaimer is for the idea that $U\setminus V$ is defined in terms of the complement. This was the wrong part - rather, the complement is defined in terms of $\setminus.$